# How to compute a lineRenderers endpoint?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

In my tower defense game I have a laser gun and it has a target.
When it shoots it always hits it's target - so far so good.

But I want the beam to go through the enemy (target) and possibly hit other enemies behind it - so I'm trying to figure out how to compute the endpoint for the lineRenderer, given it's start-point, the target-point and the **length of the beam**, so that it passes straight through the target - but still only work with 2 points, start and end.

I think it's about imagening a sphere around my tower, sin/cos/pi and extending the radius..?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out myself - using Vector3:

```
Vector3 direction = (target.position - firePoint.position);
Vector3 endPoint = firePoint.position + 
                    (direction.normalized * tower.targetRange);

laserBeam.SetPosition(0, firePoint.position);
laserBeam.SetPosition(1, endPoint);
```